# Rails 5.1 has_many through - associated fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-5.1

*(See example schema image below)*

I am attempting to query a single user from the `users` table using the `email` field, along with the `id` & `key` fields from the `applications` table. The results should contain the user found (if any), along with the application (referenced using the `key` & `id` fields) and the `applications_users` associated data.

[image: Example schema]

I can easily write SQL manually to perform this operation:

```
SELECT
  "users".*,
  "applications_users"."scopes",
  "jwt_applications".*
FROM 
  "users"
INNER JOIN
  "applications_users" ON "applications_users"."user_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN
  "jwt_applications" ON "jwt_applications"."id" = "applications_users"."application_id"
WHERE
  "users"."email" = 'rainbows@unicorns.net'
  AND "jwt_applications"."id" = '01daafc9-2169-4c78-83e9-37ac0a473e3d'
  AND "jwt_applications"."key" = 'follow_the_rainbow'
LIMIT 1
```

However, I cannot for the life of me get the query correct when using ActiveRecord.

These are the unsuccessful attempts I have made thus far:

```
user = User.where(email: args[:username]).joins(:applications).merge(
  JwtApplication.where(id: args[:application][:id], key: args[:application][:key])
).take!
```

This gets the user correctly, however Rails performs a second SQL query when I attempt to access `user.applications` (and it also returns all applications associated with the user; so it appears to disregard the `id` & `key` conditions)

```
user = User.where(email: args[:username]).joins(:applications).merge(
  JwtApplication.where(id: args[:application][:id], key: args[:application][:key])
).references(:applications_users).take!
```

This gets the user correctly and also the correct application (yay!), however Rails performs a second SQL query if I attempt to call `user.applications_users` -- it also returns a collection for all data inside the `applications_users` table (again, disregarding the `id` & `key` conditions)

```
user = User.where(email: args[:username]).joins(:applications).where(
  jwt_applications: {
    id: args[:application][:id],
    key: args[:application][:key]
  }
).take!
```

This gets the correct user, however Rails performs another SQL query when I attempt to access `user.applications` -- also returning all applications.

Anyway, hopefully a Rails genius can shed some light on this question! I will be the first to admit that I am by no means a Rails expert; I have spent the last 10 years of my professional career coding in PHP & C++, so please bear with me if this comes off as a stupid question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is something you're looking for but...
You can write ActiveRecord query like (join model should be implicitly added to your query):

`User.joins(:applications).where(email: email).where(applications: { key: key, id: id})`

Where email, key and id as params to pass to the query.

On top of that query you can use select fields to get everything you need:

`user = User.joins(:applications).where(email: email).where(applications: { key: key, id: id}).select('users.*, applications.id as appid applications.key as appkey').first`

That will give you back the user model (if present) or empty relation if nothing matches your criteria.
You can then call the fields like

`user.appid`

`user.appkey`

You can always call select `('users.*, application_users.scopes, applications.*)` which will return you all the fields in single instance (still under User model) BUT duplicate fields like id will only be shown once, that's why it's better to grab just the fields you want and give them unique identifiers like I've shown with appid and appkey.

Again, might not be exactly what you're after, but hopefully it points you in the right direction!